# Efficient 32 bit random number generator in C

Tags: random

I need to generate several 32 bit random numbers in C. For that I use

```
4294967296.0*drand48()
```

It works well. But it is slow. Can I use other generator which is more efficient?

Comment: The basic `rand()` function generates at least 15 bits.  You can shift-and-mask to compose a 32-bit value from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Marsaglia xorshift pseudorandom number generator.  The period is 2^160.  On my AMD X64, this takes 6 cycles per iteration.  That's 300 million values per second.

In his terminology, this is the [7,13,6] version.

You can make a 2^64 PNRG using only two seeds, 2^96 with three, 2^128 with four.

The final step is not part of Marsaglia's paper; he just returns v.  You can return higher-precision values by concatenating the seeds.

My call to `__rdtsc()` is just to provide a random seed.  You could use a different random generator to provide the seed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

static unsigned long
    x=123456789,
    y=362436069,
    z=521288629,
    w=88675123,
    v=886756453;
/* replace defaults with five random seed values in calling program */

unsigned long xorshift(void)
{
    unsigned long t = x^(x>>7);
    x=y; y=z; z=w; w=v;
    v=(v^(v<<6))^(t^(t<<13)); 
    return (y+y+1)*v;
} 


// This is a period 2^32 PNRG ([13,17,5]), to fill the seeds.
// You can reverse all three shift directions, you can swap the 13 and 
// the 5, and you can move the 17 last, and it works equally well.
// Oddly, this takes 9 cycles on my box, compared to 6 for the longer
// period generator above.

unsigned long 
xorshift32(void)
{
    x ^= (x<<13);
    x ^= (x>>17);
    return x ^= (x<<5);
}

void
seed()
{
    x = (unsigned long) __rdtsc();
    v = xorshift32();
    w = xorshift32();
    z = xorshift32();
    y = xorshift32();
}

int
main()
{
    int i;
    seed();
    for( i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
        printf( "%08x\n", xorshift() );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Instead of (y+y+1)*v, can I return v only?

Comment: Why worry about it?  It's less than 3 CPU cycles.  I know what I have there works, I've used it extensively.  As I said, that last line isn't in Marsaglia's paper, so it probably works, too.